# How use sql select statement to get specific column in two date range

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to retrieve a column value within a specific range of date i got a table with column name Plate_# and PR_Date i want sql statement to get list of Plate_# in certain Date Range i try this but i do not work

```
select * from PR_Schedule where Plate_#='3-08294' and PR_Date between '2014-06-09 00:00:00.000' and '2014-06-15 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: your query looks good, where is the issue ?

Comment: use the perticular colomn in select query instead of *

Answer (score 0):

i would use < or > instead of between

```
select * from PR_Schedule where Plate_#='3-08294' and PR_Date > '2014-06-09 00:00:00.000' and PR_Date < '2014-06-15 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case date range from code as parameter:

```
@FromDate datetime,
@ToDate datetime

AS

select * from PR_Schedule
where
Plate_#='3-08294'
AND
PR_Date between @FromDate and @ToDate
```

IN case of a static date as the question:

```
select * from PR_Schedule
where
Plate_#='3-08294'
AND
PR_Date between '06/09/2014'and '06/15/2014'
```